# Customization of default email for app script uninstall instruction

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I customize the default apps_script_notification email which comes to my **inbox** when I use/authorize my google app `script` for the first time. If I can not customize, can I read it from gmail and edit it? Will that be legal and not against Google's policy? I need to update some of the content here.. please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cant, nor can you edit a sent email (which I hope is never available as it doesnt make sense to edit a sent/received email)